# Implement custom CopyToDataTable method while keeping the original one

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I followed the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) and created the custom CopyToDataTable method with no problem. BUT CopyToDataTable is already called in other places and they are now getting errors because they all point to the new one that I created.

Is there way to keep both version and get both referenced correctly?

Comment: Assuming this is the namespace of your extension class: `MyExtensions.DataTableExtensions`. Then you have to add `using MyExtensions.DataTableExtensions;` only where you want to use it. Btw, this is the correct link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

Comment: Don't give your custom method the same name, cut off the problem at the pass. Give it an unambiguous name.

Comment: I corrected the link. And I will try both approaches. Thanks.